# $app->finish not triggering

Tags: symfony, event-handling, event-listener, silex

Got a strange one here.  I'm just about done with a Silex app, but am having problems getting $app->finish to trigger.  Here's my code:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->get('/', function (Request $request) {
    $batchProcess = function () {
        long_process();
    };
    $app->finish($batchProcess);

    return $app->json("ok", 200);
};

$app->run();
```

So here's the problem: the batch process never runs! Trying to find the bug, I added a var_export into the "on" function in Silex\Application:

```
/**
 * Adds an event listener that listens on the specified events.
 *
 * @param string   $eventName The event to listen on
 * @param callable $callback  The listener
 * @param integer  $priority  The higher this value, the earlier an event
 *                            listener will be triggered in the chain (defaults to 0)
 */
public function on($eventName, $callback, $priority = 0)
{
    $this['dispatcher'] = $this->share($this->extend('dispatcher', function ($dispatcher, $app) use ($callback, $priority, $eventName) {
        $dispatcher->addListener($eventName, $callback, $priority);

        return $dispatcher;
    }));
    var_export($this['dispatcher']);
}
```

When the var_export is in there, everything works (though the kernel runs the batch process before sending any data). When var_export is commented out, "ok" it returned immediately and the batch process never runs.

What am I doing wrong? Why is the kernel terminating without executing my process?

Answer (score 0):

See [comments by Igor Wiedler](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/silex-php/3I9olVTkiuk):

> There may be a way to achieve it with two changes to the Response
>   class.
>
> - The first is adding `ob_flush()` before `flush()` in `Response::send()`.
> - The second is setting the `content-length` header.

I was able to achieve the same effect without modifying the `Response` class. First, you need to move the callback you set in `finish` middleware outside of the `get` method, and check manually the route (`'GET_'` in this case responds to `'/'` path):

```
$app->finish(function() {
    if ('GET_' === $request->attributes->get('_route')) {
        long_process();
    }
});
```

Then here is how you `get` method should look like:

```
$app->get('/', function(Request $request) use ($app) { 
    $content = json_encode(array(
        'status' => 'ok',
    ));
    $response = new Response($content, 200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Length', strlen($content));
    $response->send();
    ob_flush();

    return $response;
});
```

Setting the content-length is very important, or the JSON content will be sent twice, as $response is returned in the method, and sent by Silex.